# specific line in file to string

Tags: python, file

```
with open("Status.txt", "x") as Status: #makes a file 
    UserName = Status.read() #reads the file

with open("Status.txt", "w") as StatusFileWrite:
    StatusFileWrite.write("Hello " + UserName + " :)")
```

is the code I wrote and it says a error that it can't read the contents if the file
and how do I change instantly change that the file has when it is created

how do I specify what line it reads

I was ecspecting it to make the string to the contents of the file

this Is the error

```
UserName = Status.read()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: Don't make us guess what the error is.  Edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: ok I will edit I just made this account

Comment: `"x"`, as the second parameter to `open()`, means "create a new file and open it for writing".  Why did you expect to be able to read anything from such a file?

Comment: You opened the file with the `"x"` argument, which means the file is opened for _writing_, not _reading_.  Why are you using `"x"` if you want to read the file?

Comment: Assume that Status.txt does not exist. Then... the first time you run the code shown in the question you'll get the UnsupportedOperation because the file was opened exclusively for writing. Then run it a second time and you get a FileExistsError exception because it was created albeit unreadable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, write to the file

```
with open("Status.txt", "w") as StatusFileWrite:
    StatusFileWrite.write("Hello User :)")
```

Now, read from the file

```
with open("Status.txt", "r") as Status:
    UserName = Status.readline()  # Reads the first line
print("Read from file:", UserName)
```

Comment: If you need to read a specific line, usw a for loop and only read that specific line

Comment: @Smorpy that's good, please consider marking this a correct answer if it worked for you

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: I found out how

Answer (score 0):

First, you understand the File

> Open()

function Parameters

Here are the following parameters.

- 'r'  Open a file for reading. (default)
- 'w'  Open a file for writing. Creates a new file if it does not exist or truncates the file if it exists.
- 'x'  Open a file for exclusive creation. If the file already exists, the operation fails.
- 'a'  Open for appending at the end of the file without truncating it. Creates a new file if it does not exist.
- 't'  Open in text mode. (default)
- 'b'  Open in binary mode.
- '+'  Open a file for updating (reading and writing)

According to your code example, it should be something like.

```
UserName = "John"  # Assuming you have a variable named UserName

with open("Status.txt", "w") as StatusFileWrite:
    StatusFileWrite.write("Hello " + UserName + " :)")

# Reading from the file
with open("Status.txt", "r") as Status:
    content = Status.read()
    print(content)  # You can use the content variable as needed
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the corrected version of my code, thanks to @CtrlZ for pointingout my mistake. Also I know this is not what you want because I saw your accepted answer but it might help future viewers:

```
# using "r" instead of "w" to correctly
# read the file
# Read from the file
with open(filename, "r") as Status:
    UserName = Status.read()
# Write to the file
with open(filename, "w") as StatusFileWrite:
    StatusFileWrite.write("Hello " + UserName + " :)")
```

I leave this previous answer because it would fit your descriptions in the commented part of your code but is wrong as I misread the username defining part. It might help future searchers.

```
# Create an empty file
with open("Status.txt", "w"):
    pass
# Read from the file
with open(filename, "r") as Status:
    UserName = Status.read()
# Write to the file
with open(filename, "w") as StatusFileWrite:
    StatusFileWrite.write("Hello " + UserName + " :)")
```

Comment: It won't work. The contents of the file will ultimately be **Hello  :)** What did you expect to be able to read from a newly created (empty) file?

Comment: @CtrlZ What you say is true, but if you look at his comments on the code, he first wants to create a file and then read the file which is what I did, I was under the impression that he would implement my code to his work ok wait now I understand what you have meant, I misread the line about geting the username. I will edit my code. thanks for bringing this up.